# Finding a primitive element (field extension)

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $L:=\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})$ with $\omega:=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\sqrt{3}$.

How to find a primitive element of the field extension $\mathbb{Q} \subset L$?

My idea was to show that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\sqrt[3]{2})$

So I started with:

$\omega + \sqrt[3]{2}\in \mathbb{Q}(\omega, \sqrt[3]{2}) \Rightarrow \mathbb{Q}(\omega+\sqrt[3]{2}) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\omega,\sqrt[3]{2})$

For the other direction I got:

$(\omega+\sqrt[3]{2})^3=3+3(-1)^{\frac{2}{3}}2^{\frac{2}{3}}-3(-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}\sqrt[3]{2}$

$\Rightarrow \sqrt[3]{2}\in \mathbb{Q}(\omega+ \sqrt[3]{2})$

Now I don't know how to continue to show that $\omega \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega+ \sqrt[3]{2})$.

What has to be done next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you proved that $\sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega+\sqrt[3]{2})$, then $$
\omega=(\omega+\sqrt[3]{2})-\sqrt[3]{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega+\sqrt[3]{2})
$$
and you are done.